How to link FLAC in CMake sfml?
I am new to cmake and sfml, and i want to learn cpp game development.
on my linux machine i got this error:
[1/1] Linking CXX executable SFMLApp
FAILED: SFMLApp 
: && /usr/bin/c++ -g  CMakeFiles/SFMLApp.dir/main.cpp.o -o SFMLApp -L/home/issa/CLionProjects/Graphics_demo/SFML_LIBRARY_DIR -Wl,-rpath,/home/issa/CLionProjects/Graphics_demo/SFML_LIBRARY_DIR:/home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib  /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.6.1  /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-window-d.so.2.6.1  /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1  /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-system-d.so.2.6.1 && :
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libFLAC.so.12, needed by /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_decoder_skip_single_frame'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_decoder_process_until_end_of_metadata'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_decoder_seek_absolute'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_encoder_init_file'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_encoder_finish'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_decoder_finish'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_encoder_process_interleaved'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_encoder_set_channels'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_encoder_new'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_decoder_new'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_decoder_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_encoder_set_sample_rate'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_decoder_process_single'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_decoder_get_state'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_decoder_init_stream'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_encoder_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.6.1: undefined reference to `FLAC__stream_encoder_set_bits_per_sample'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

i have libflac-dev installed:
 $ sudo find /* -name libFLAC.so.*
...
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8.3.0
...

What change should i do in to link libflac-dev in CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(Graphics_demo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(Graphics_demo main.cpp)

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "SFMLApp")
set(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR "/home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/include")
set(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR "/home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib")
set(SFML_DIR "/home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/cmake/SFML")

link_directories(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR)
include_directories(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR)

find_package(SFML 2.6.1 COMPONENTS system window graphics audio network)
if (SFML_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "SFML_INCLUDE_DIR: ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    message(STATUS "SFML_LIBRARIES: ${SFML_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "SFML_VERSION: ${SFML_VERSION}")
endif ()

add_executable(SFMLApp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SFMLApp sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system sfml-audio)

why this command work without an errors while the cmake one doesn't?
 g++ main.cpp -o main -lsfml-system -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-window


If the SFML library has a cmake configuration, you don't need to call link_directories(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR) nor include_directories(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR).

You should read the error carefully. Line four of the output explains that it is looking for libFLAC.so.12 instead of 8. Another worry is that you are linking debug libraries, whereas your manual g++ call is linking release libraries. I don't understand how you were able to build debug libraries against a version of libFLAC that is not present on your system, but there it is..

@Botje warning: libFLAC.so.12, it's a warning, and also libFac.so.12 is not available for ubuntu 22.04lts, and also pay attention that the command i used will use the apt version of my SFML.

Yes. It is warning that the file needed by one of your dependencies is not found. That is why you get linking errors.

@Botje so why using the command g++ still work just fine.

Because that is a) linking libraries from the system instead of /home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1 and b) linking release libraries instead of debug libraries. If you add -L/home/issa/Cpp-libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib to your manual compilation command you will get similar errors.

solution:
I finally got the solution, by installing libflac12 manually from here, after that i got the faild to load sound error and also solved here.
Explanation:
The apt vertion of sfml which is installed when using sudo apt install libsfml-dev is 2.5.1 works fine with libFLAC.so.8, and this version is used with the g++ command since it's executed from the system terminal.
The version of sfml which i am using in the CMakeLists.txt is 2.6.1 which requires libFLAC.so.12.
